# obtener value de span

Tags: javascript, html5

```js
$('#usuarios').children('ul').each(function () {
   console.log(this);
});
```

```css
#usuarios ul{
display:inline-block;
}
ul{
width:100px;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="usuarios">
  <ul><span>ayer</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>amor</span></ul>
  <ul><span>gab</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>rio</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>bestia</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>gorro</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>abrigo</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>jaula</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>zorra</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>tele</span> </ul>
</div>
```

como obtengo las palabras que contiene span?

Comment: Esto no es lo que te sugería que hicieses en la otra pregunta. La idea sería que fuese algo como esto otro: `<ul id="usuarios"><li><div>Usuario 1</div></li><li><div>Usuario 2</div></li>....</ul>`. El código que compartes no es HTML válido.

Comment: Y relacionado con esta pregunta directamente: tienes que concretarla un poco. ¿Qué palabras quieres obtener?¿Las de todos los `span` o sólo las de alguno en concreto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define una matriz, en el ejemplo siguiente es `data`, y luego usa el método `push` para agregar los valores a esta.

Ejemplo:

```js
var data = [];
$('#usuarios').children('ul').each(function () {
   data.push($(this).children('span').text());
});
console.log(data);
```

```css
#usuarios ul{
display:inline-block;
}
ul{
width:100px;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="usuarios">
  <ul><span>ayer</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>amor</span></ul>
  <ul><span>gab</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>rio</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>bestia</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>gorro</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>abrigo</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>jaula</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>zorra</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>tele</span> </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Estimado,
Prueba esto

```js
$('#usuarios').children('ul').each(function () {
   console.log(jQuery(this).text())
   // ó console.log(jQuery(this).html())
});
```

```css
#usuarios ul{
display:inline-block;
}
ul{
width:100px;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="usuarios">
  <ul><span>ayer</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>amor</span></ul>
  <ul><span>gab</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>rio</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>bestia</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>gorro</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>abrigo</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>jaula</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>zorra</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>tele</span> </ul>
</div>
```

Saludos,

Answer (score 1):

En tu codigo veo un par de errores:

1. El codigo HTML esta mal, la sintaxis para una [lista HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp) debería ser:

```html
<ul>
   <li>Primer elemento</li>
   <li>Segundo elemento</li>
   <li>Tercer elemento</li>
</ul>
```

2. Un elemento como un span no contiene un value (eso es para inputs tipo *text*), contiene [innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp), que en este caso seria el texto de cada elemento de la lista.

Editando un poco el codigo javascript puedes solucionarlo:

```js
$('#usuarios > ul').children('span').each(function () { 
  // Cambiamos el selector de jQuery para que busque directamente los ul de #usuarios
  // y procese cada span
   console.log(this.innerHTML); // Utilizamos innerHTML para acceder al texto del span
});
```

```css
#usuarios ul{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="usuarios">
  <ul><span>ayer</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>amor</span></ul>
  <ul><span>gab</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>rio</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>bestia</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>gorro</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>abrigo</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>jaula</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>zorra</span> </ul>
  <ul><span>tele</span> </ul>
</div>
```

**PD:**
Mi recomendación es que corrijas el código HTML, para que jQuery tenga que recorrer menos DOM a la hora de procesar todos los elementos, aparte de que un mal codigo HTML puede causar defectos en segun que navegadores:

```js
$('#usuarios').children('li').each(function () {
   console.log(this.innerHTML); // innerHTML accede al texto del elemento y NO al elemento
});
```

```css
#usuarios li{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="usuarios">
  <li>ayer</li>
  <li>amor</li>
  <li>gab</li>
  <li>rio</li>
  <li>bestia</li>
  <li>gorro</li>
  <li>abrigo</li>
  <li>jaula</li>
  <li>zorra</li>
  <li>tele</li>
</ul>
```